# Turn on light when camera active

Tags: macos, automator, camera

I'm looking for a method to have a light bulb turn on when my camera is active on my macbook-  sort of an "On Air" light.  I know there are arduino solutions for activating the light- I'm just not sure how to begin the search for the method of telling arduino/automator/etc: hey the camera is activated now do this....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 2):

[Oversight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html) is a product by Objective-See that performs low-level detection of when the camera is used. I posted a screenshot from a [talk by Patrick Wardle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InL3YA_6P6s) that discusses this specifically, along with some sample code of how to invoke this via AVFoundation notifications. The portion most relevant to you starts at 43 minutes.

If this application you're describing is for personal use, then I think it's fine, but note that the type of callback you're looking for is that the same one that malicious tools can use to also record your [Facetime/Skype video and upload it](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/nz7qeg/ex-nsa-hacker-creates-tool-to-warn-you-of-webcam-spies) to a third party. So, please note and understand the full context of what you're proposing if you're not already aware of it.

[image]